# I have a problem in the structure

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a problem with this sentence
"When Adubon was Painting was a time of major scientific inquiry "
Why the second was exerted without subject?

Answer (score 1):

But the second *was* does have a subject.

You should parse the sentence this way:

> [When Adubon was Painting] <sup>*was*</sup> a time of major scientific inquiry.

In other words, the subject of the sentence is the subject phrase *when Adubon was Painting*, which, itself, contains the subject Adubon. Depending on how you look at it, the sentence contains two subjects, with one embedded inside the other.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed